# Layers in 4 Tier Architecture in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, architecture

As per [this](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article18.aspx) article in 4 tier architecture, Business object is also consider as layer.

In this application we will have following 4-Tiers (As given on blog)
1. Business Object [BO] 
2. Business Access Layer [BAL] 
3. Data Access Layer [DAL] 
4. UI (4-Tier) folder [UI]

I want to clear, In Software architecture, Do we consider Business Object as a separate layer ?

My second question is

If we have two tier architecture it means we can have two physical servers, One server can have only DB (Database Server) and other server will consist Presentation (UI), Business Logic, Data Access Layer and Business Object. Is it correct ?

and

In three tier we can deploy UI layer on one server (T1) ,  Business Logic, Data Access Layer, Business Object on an other server (T2) and Database separate  server (T3). In this case we have to create service (.Net service or WCF or remoting) to expose object for UI layer.

I am not sure about 4 tier architecture. As per  [[this]](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article18.aspx) article it describe 4 layers includes business object (BO). I am not sure whether we consider BO as layer or not ?

Looking for kind help as i found.

Comment: read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430014/N-Tier-Architecture-and-Tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, layer is used to denote logical grouping while tier is used for physical grouping. So first thing, I would typically called it as  n-Layer architecture rather than 4-Tier architecture. See [this article for more about layers and tiers](http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/Application_Architecture_Guide_-_Chapter_9_-_Layers_and_Tiers)

Now, BO layer sighted in the article is really what typically known as DTO (data transfer objects) as those are POCO entities - these are considered as cross-cutting components and can be used from any layer. Other infrastructure components (such as logging, audit trail etc) also falls into similar cross-cutting components. Although, its a logical group, they are not generally called layer.

How you host your layers in physical groups (processes/servers) would decide number of tiers. So you can have database as one tier, app server (IIS) hosting UI/BL/DAL as another tier and browser/client as third tier. Again, you can host BL/DAL on app server and UI on web server creating more tiers.